# Uniquely identifying MySQL entries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stumped. Here's my relevant code:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($getdata)){

$myid = $data["myid"]; //unique entry identifier for table rows
$method = $data["method"];
$category = $data["category"];
$company = $data["company"];
$datestarted = $data["datestarted"];
$initialfee = $data["initialfee"];
$ongoingfee = $data["ongoingfee"];

echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='14%' height='60px'>";
echo $method;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='20%' height='60px'>";
echo $category;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='20%' height='60px'>";
echo $company;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='12%' height='60px'>";
echo $datestarted;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='12%' height='60px'>";
echo $initialfee;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='12%' height='60px'>";
echo $ongoingfee;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='10%'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='' class='button' value='Remove'>";
echo "</td>";
}
```

What's happening here, is that a table is going to be displayed and each row in that table will look as coded above. There could be any number of entries, but probably in a range of 1-6. At the end of each entry is a remove button. Once clicked, the user is forwarded to a page where that entry will then be subject to removal from the table. My problem is identifying which entry the user wants to remove based on which "remove" button they clicked. If the number of rows weren't dynamic, I could just give each input button a unique name ahead of time and that could help. How can I uniquely identify what row I need to remove on the removal page after a remove button is clicked? I can't use sessions because the session variable $myid would just change each time a new row were made. Pulling from a database won't help obviously because I lack a unique identifier on the following page.

I have an idea of setting the name of each button equal to each unique $myid, which would make that unique $myid the only $_POST variable that would travel to the removal page depending on the button pressed. On the removal page I would just set $myid equal to that post variable. However, even if it's the only post variable available, how do I reference it to be equal to $myid on the removal page without knowing the name of it? Because I won't know the name of the $_POST variable that traveled to the removal page.

The answer's probably simple, but for whatever reason it isn't coming to me on this night.

Thanks for your help. Honestly don't know what I would do without this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new form for each row, with a hidden field containing the ID of the record you want to delete.

```
echo "<form>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='10%'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$id'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='' class='button' value='Remove'>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, should have thought of that one.

Comment: And if you want to do it as a single form with a series of multiple check boxes, use a check box element with a name="remove[$id]" for each item and value of something (eg value="1" or value="delete") you can then iterate through an array of id's stored as $_GET['remove'] or $_POST['remove'] or alternatively concatenate the ID's and do a single MySQL query with the IN() function

Answer (score 0):

At first I want to say your `tr` tag is not well placed, and create a `form` to solve your problem

Try this:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($getdata)){

    $myid = $data["myid"]; //unique entry identifier for table rows
    $method = $data["method"];
    $category = $data["category"];
    $company = $data["company"];
    $datestarted = $data["datestarted"];
    $initialfee = $data["initialfee"];
    $ongoingfee = $data["ongoingfee"];


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='mymenu' width='14%' height='60px'>";
    echo $method;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td class='mymenu' width='20%' height='60px'>";
    echo $category;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td class='mymenu' width='20%' height='60px'>";
    echo $company;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td class='mymenu' width='12%' height='60px'>";
    echo $datestarted;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td class='mymenu' width='12%' height='60px'>";
    echo $initialfee;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td class='mymenu' width='12%' height='60px'>";
    echo $ongoingfee;
    echo "</td>";



    echo "<td class='mymenu' width='10%'>";
    echo "<form>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$id."'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='' class='button' value='Remove'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this @Lock forgot to put `"` in form.

```
<?php
echo "<form>";
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<td class='mymenu' width='10%'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$id'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='' class='button' value='Remove'>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr></table>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```